# SQLAlchemy: different output on queries "field IS NULL" and "IS NOT NULL" on aliased model

Tags: python, orm, sqlalchemy, relationship, alias

I've noticed a very strange behaviour when querying against field from aliased model. Seems that SQLAlchemy breaks the aliasing while filtering relation against NOT NULL condition. Here is an example:

```py
Base = declarative_base()

class Parent(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'parents'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    children = relation('Child', back_populates='parent')

class Child(Base):
    __tablename__ = 'children'
    id = Column(Integer, primary_key=True)
    parent_id = Column(Integer, ForeignKey('parents.id'))
    parent = relation('Parent', back_populates='children', uselist=False)

aChild = aliased(Child)

print Session.query(aChild.id).filter(aChild.parent == None)
""" SELECT children_1.id AS children_1_id
    FROM children AS children_1
    WHERE children_1.parent_id IS NULL
"""

print Session.query(aChild.id).filter(aChild.parent != None)
""" SELECT children_1.id AS children_1_id
    FROM children AS children_1, children
    WHERE children.parent_id IS NOT NULL
"""

print Session.query(aChild.id).filter(~(aChild.parent == None))
""" SELECT children_1.id AS children_1_id
    FROM children AS children_1
    WHERE children_1.parent_id IS NOT NULL
"""
```

You can see there is a cross join in the second query, while 1st and 3rd are working as expected. Is there any explanation or solution for this issue except the 3rd example?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You found a bug in sqlalchemy! I submitted a bug report to the sqlalchemy team, and have worked out a potential fix. You can check out the status [here](https://bitbucket.org/zzzeek/sqlalchemy/issue/3310/relationship-__ne__-does-not-handle)

A bugfix is now in place, and you can pull from top of tree to build/fix your sqlalchemy package.